# Jordan-Chevalley decomposition for non-algebraically closed fields?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

Say that we have a field $\mathbb{K}$ which is not necessarily algebraically closed, and $V$ a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{K}$. Given an endomorphism $X \in \text{End}_{\mathbb{K}}(V)$, what are the most general conditions under which $X$ has a Jordan-Chevalley decomposition? Recall that this is a decomposition
$$X = X_{ss} + X_{n}$$
where $X_{ss}$ is semisimple, $X_n$ is nilpotent, and $[X_{ss}, X_n]= 0$.

In every reference I've checked the proof that every linear endomorphism has a Jordan-Chevalley decomposition is given for $\mathbb{K}$ complex or otherwise algebraically closed, but in the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Chevalley_decomposition) it is implied that it holds for $\mathbb{K}$ a perfect field. I would really appreciate if someone could point me to a reference that proves it in the more general case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows from Galois theory and the uniqueness of $X_{ss}$ and $X_n$.  Pick a basis for $V$, so we can represent $X$ as a matrix with entries in $\mathbb{K}$ and $X_{ss}$ and $X_n$ as matrices with entries in the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{K}}$.  Note that if $\alpha$ is any automorphism of $\overline{\mathbb{K}}$ over $\mathbb{K}$, we can apply it to all the entries of our matrices, and $\alpha(X_{ss})$ and $\alpha(X_n)$ will be a Jordan-Chevalley decomposition for $\alpha(X)=X$.  By uniqueness of the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition, $\alpha(X_{ss})=X_{ss}$ and $\alpha(X_n)=X_n$.  If $\mathbb{K}$ is perfect, Galois theory now implies that all the entries of $X_{ss}$ and $X_n$ are actually in $\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I can perform the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition of an endomorphism $X: V \to V$ of a real vector space $V$ by just taking the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition of the complexification $1 \otimes X: \mathbb{C} \otimes V \to  \mathbb{C} \otimes V$? I thought that the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition of a complex matrix was obtained from the Jordan normal form, by separting the matrix into diagonal and off-diagonal components. Wouldn't this result in $X_{ss}$ possibly having complex entries?

Comment: It may have complex entries in the basis for its Jordan normal form, but if you change back to the original basis (over which $X$ had real entries), $X_{ss}$ will have real entries again.

Comment: For instance, if $X$ itself is semisimple with nonreal eigenvalues, its Jordan normal form does not have real entries.  But that doesn't mean $X_{ss}$ does not come from a real matrix, since in the original basis $X_{ss}$ is just $X$.

Comment: Ah OK that makes sense; thanks!